# How can I get a line from an object?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tweepy

So I'm kind of new to python and I want to make a twitter bot.
I did this:

```
print(api.get_user(screen_name="My account's handle"))
```

(while having "tweepy" imported and given my script the correct authentication keys / tokens etc)

That line printed a lot of text, what i want to do is get the number afte "in_reply_to_status_id="

which is 1048042979359936513

The text that was printed is pasted inside here:
https://pastebin.com/ZVWzYEJw
(had to use pastebit because it was too long and has links)

I hope this makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely familiar with the tweepy's response object but if it's as you described above i.e.the User object, then you can probably try this:

```
import json

response = "{'response':" + User._json + "}"
data = json.loads(response)
data['in_reply_to_status_id']
>>>1048042979359936513
```

Edit: If in_reply_to_status_id is an attribute of User then you should be able to call it by just `User.in_reply_to_status_id`

Comment: got "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not 'dict'"

Comment: Is it an attribute and not actually wrapped inside the returned json? It'll be helpful if you can provide the actual output

Comment: I added a link with the output

Comment: Please try
 
`response  = "{'response':" + User._json + "}"`

`json.loads(response)`

Comment: TypeError: must be str, not dict :/
(thanks for trying to help)

Comment: From the link you provided, it looks like it's provided as a User object attribute too. Calling `User.in_reply_to_status_id` didn't work too?

Comment: user.status.id does the trick. FINALLY found it, thanks to you! ty!

Comment: I was just reflecting on it too. If User._json is a dict object then you should be able to call it by just User. _json['in_reply_to_status_id'] without parsing it. Anyway, glad that you can proceed with your project!

Answer (score 0):

Tweepy's [`API.get_user()`](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.get_user) method returns `User` object. The long text you see in the response is the string representation of `User` object.As @kerwei says, you can check which properties exist in this object by checking keys in `user._json` (this is a dictionary object).

But `in_reply_to_status_id` is in the `Status` object (representing a tweet) not in `User` object. So at first, you should get a `Status` object by using [`API.get_status()`](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.get_status) etc.. After that, you should be able to get `in_reply_to_status_id` in this object.

You can get `in_reply_to_status_id` from `Status` object like this:

```
>>> status = api.get_status(1234567890)
>>> reply_id = status.in_reply_to_status_id
>>> print(reply_id)
```